# Jump to another page in a Single Page Application

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am writing a system for our forklift drivers in XPages. Basically our machines in production are going to get a iPod with a single big button on it. When they press the button I add a document to the Notes database (see code below). The forklife drivers have an iPad with a view that displays all the calls - they then select one call and drive to that machine. Once the machine operator has pressed the call button they can see some computed text saying that a forklift is command and another Cancel button.

I have it working (well, sort of) - but cannot seem to get the page in the "Single Page Application" to refresh.

This is the code that I have on a button - how do I now get the page to refresh - or how do I move to another page (in the "Single Page Application" using JavaScript) - sorry, I am just stumped!

Thanx for any help
Ursus

```
// setup date and time
var dt:NotesDateTime = session.createDateTime("Today 12");
dt.setNow();

// create a new document
var newDoc = database.createDocument();

// now set your fields 
newDoc.replaceItemValue ("form",                "fmRuf");
newDoc.replaceItemValue ("maschineName",        sessionScope.displayName);
newDoc.replaceItemValue ("maschineNotesName",   sessionScope.notesName);
newDoc.replaceItemValue ("maschineUm",          dt);
newDoc.appendItemValue  ("status",              "20");
newDoc.computeWithForm(true, false);

// save the document
newDoc.save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select the refresh mode to complete, the whole site should refreshed.

[image]

```
<xp:button value="label" id="button4">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"  refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://SOME CODE}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Or try this code

```
<xp:button  value="Beschriftung"    id="button4">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:actionGroup condition="#{javascript://someCode}"></xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:openPage name="/YourXpages.xsp"></xp:openPage>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I have exactly that option set - the page does not refresh though. Is there some way to move to another page in the Single Page Application?

Comment: Hi. I did what your second example and it now seems to be running... my (first) XPages app is VERY bady written - but it does currently run :) Thank you for your help